# For loops fills only last row in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, rvest

I'm a beginner in R. I have a code that scrapes some data from a website (Rvest package) and then stores it as text in a matrix(which I'll later combine with other matrices to form a data frame).
To populate the matrix I'm using a for loop. The code had been working fine, but when I opened it today, it started filling in only the last iteration, and I don't get what the problem is:

```
all = matrix(nrow = length(urls))
for (i in length(urls)) {
  p = read_html (urls[i]) %>% 
                   html_nodes("p") %>%
                   html_text() %>%
                   as.character();
                 all[i,] = paste(p, collapse="_")
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks (:

Comment: In such situations, you always want to check your iteration. Change `for(i in length(urls))` to i in `for(i in 1:length(urls))` or `for(i in seq_along(urls))`.

Comment: Indeed that was the case! such a stupid mistake. Thanks!